# MySQL/Doctrine: allowing null fields on insert, but not update

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

Sometimes there's a need to create an entity with some undefined fields, but prevent storing undefined values on subsequent updates. For example, the User entity in the example below has to be persisted before resolving the value of the 'name' field. Once created, it should be persisted again only when the name field is not null.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id; //autoincrement

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name; //null at the time of creation

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $birthday; //null at the time of creation
}
```

Persisting the above entity with the null name field would result in 'Column cannot be null' SQL error. Ideally, there would be two separate "NOT NULL ON INSERT" and "NOT NULL ON UPDATE" constraints. Since this is not the case other solutions must be used.

- A simple solution is to remove "not null" constraint from table to allow null inserts and
  validate entity on the PHP side to prevent setting null values on update. This approach requires extra effort and care.
- Another solution is to define not null default values that would
  stand    for 'undefined', like $name='', $birthday=new Date('1900-01-01'). But this
  would    require translating these values to empty before using them
  (for    example, displaying a form to set the actual name and date).
- Yet another solution would be to create "EntityData" object and add
  nullable OneToOne relationship. This is quite cool, because not null constraint is relaxed for the whole group but not individual fields. 
  However, this requires creating separate tables/entities for User
  identity and its contents.

Any other ideas about how to best handle these cases?

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events maybe you can use `preUpdate` event to check if the entity has values different than null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preUpdate` event from doctrine ORM to check if properties are different from null.

```
        /** @PreUpdate */
     public function doStuffOnPreUpdate()
     {
            $this->value = 'changed from preUpdate callback!';
     }
```

You have to take in considaration to add `@HasLifecycleCallbacks` annotation on the entity also.
Documentation link: 
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events